# Intellij default Java class and some default methods / html with an default template/skeleton

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, concordion

I am not sure if this is viable, just giving it a try to see what comes out of the discussion.

1) When a new java class is created in intelliJ under test package/ with the name ending MyFirsttest, then the I want the class to extend a base class and also add few functions by default.

2) Similarly when I create a html file in intellij, it should give a basic skeleton.

Thanks,
Prashan.

Comment: I'm not sure about Java class but i have done this for `HTML` in the settings

Comment: Could you detail the stps how it is done....thank you

Comment: Go to `settings`  under Editor `File and code templates` choose `HTML` and add your style with that template.

Comment: Thanks mate will give it a try tomorrow...